# Accessing a using declaration within a functor: a scope related question

Tags: c++, scope, using, functor

The following piece of test code doesn't compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>

using std::string;
using std::function;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void process (string);

int main (void){

    string s = "This string";

    process (s);

    return 0;
}

void process (string s){

    function<void(iter_t,iter_t)>print = [&] (iter_t start, iter_t finish){

        cout << *start << endl;
        cout << *finish << endl;

        return;
    };

    auto begin = s.begin();
    auto end = s.end() - 1;

    using iter_t = typeid(iterator_traits<begin>::iterator_category); 

    print(begin,end);

    return;
}
```

The compilation error that I get is:

```
code.cpp: In function void process(std::string):
code.cpp:24:16: error: iter_t was not declared in this scope
  function<void(iter_t,iter_t)>print = [&] (iter_t start, iter_t finish){

                ^~~~~~
```

I was expecting that the `using` type alias declaration `iter_t` should be visible within the functor `print()`, as the functor itself has been defined within the same scope as the `using` type declaration. Obviously, I am missing something.

Comment: You first have to define your type, than use it. Try moving the using to the first line of the function

Comment: `std::cout << i << '\n'; int i = 42;` doesn't work either.

Comment: Your `print` function just prints two separate characters. Is that desired?

Comment: Comments about the code: C++ doesn’t require `void` to declare empty argument lists. So don’t use it, it’s cargo cult programming. Pass complex types by `const&` unless you intend to make a copy. That is, your `process` function should have the signature `void process(std::string const& s)`. Why declare `print` as a `std::function`? Just use the lambda directly. Lastly, remove the redundant `return;` statement, it adds no clarity, just clutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your alias definition does not make sense.
What you want is the type of the iterator.
It should be

```
using iter_t = decltype(begin);
```

Or

```
using iter_t = std::string::iterator;
```

Second, you have to move this to the beginning of the function,
before the definition of `print`.

Moreover, I can't understand your `print` function.
It prints two separate characters.

Modified code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>

using std::string;
using std::function;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void process (string);

int main (void){

    string s = "This string";

    process (s);

    return 0;
}

void process (string s){

    using iter_t = std::string::iterator;

    function<void(iter_t,iter_t)>print = [&] (iter_t start, iter_t finish){

        cout << *start << endl;
        cout << *finish << endl;

        return;
    };

    auto begin = s.begin();
    auto end = s.end() - 1;

    print(begin,end);

    return;
}
```

This (correctly?) outputs

```
T
g
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exclusive to `using`, it's how the language works.

Your `using` will only be valid in block scope, more specifically from the moment your `using` declaration exists until the end of the block scope.

The reason your code doesn't work is the same reason this code doesn't work:

```
std::cout << foo;
int foo = 0;
```